# create pop up instead of notification from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, notifications

i need to display pop up message in the center of screen , after reading in few forums i found out that it can be achieved by starting a new transparent activity .

this is my code :

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClassName(context,
            "com.ui.activity.NotificationActivity");
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(i);

}
```

this work's but :

**if application is in background than the application will come to the foreground with the pop up on it**  (if the application is not on background this work's great ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want your app to be brought to the foreground when this popup is shown, you need to ensure that `NotificationActivity` has a different task affinity than the rest of your application.

In the manifest, add this to the `<activity>` definition for `NotificationActivity`:

```
android:taskAffinity=""
```

Without this, the default task affinity for all Activities is the same, so that when Android looks for a task to launch `NotificationActivity` into, and your app is already running, Android launches `NotificationActivity` into that task and brings it to the foreground.

If you change the task affinity, Android won't look for an existing task to launch `NotificationActivity` into, and will just create a new task.